# How did we find the values of trigonometric ratios in old time?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

Initially, trigonometric ratios were defined for right triangles, it means that trigonometric ratios were defined only for acute angles. And then we generalized it with the help of the unit circle, later we gave the analytical definition of trigonometric functions by using power series expansion. Today, we can find the value of any trigonometric function for all real numbers by using power series up to the desired accuracy.

But I am interested in the time when trigonometric ratios were defined only for acute angles. At that time how were we able to find the value of trigonometric ratios? Of course, for some few angles like $30^\circ$, $45^\circ$ etc we could find it by using elementary geometry. But what about other angles? Was it purely experimental or some better methods were available?

Thanks

Comment: You should ask this in hsm.stackexchange.com . Btw none of us here were able to find these ratios.

Comment: See, eg, [Ptolemy's Table of Chords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_table_of_chords).